# Why does my eclipse does not produce the R.java file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, r.java-file

I am new to android but when I run the eclipse (which I installed ADT Plugin and android SDK) I found that my eclipse is not generating R.java file with a error message(as shown in figure)

[image]

How to rectify that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Chris This is simply untrue. From [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html): *Caution: Android Studio is currently available as an early access preview. Several features are either incomplete or not yet implemented and you may encounter bugs. If you are not comfortable using an unfinished product, you may want to instead download (or continue to use) the ADT Bundle (Eclipse with the ADT Plugin).*

Comment: usually when the R file is not generated is because there is something wrong with one of your xml files. check them to make sure there are no errors in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the android bundle here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

It is and eclipse version with everything needed for android already installed.

I had the same trouble as you, switched to this one and everything worked at the first try